# PyQt4 installation on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

Please help to finish installation of PyQt.
So I think I successfully installed SPI and PyQt as it is mentioned in the reiverbankcomputing. (https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)
(at least no errors where raised during installation).
However when in python shell I import PyQt, python does not recognize it:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

To my opinion the issues is in PATH variable. I am not root in Linux, so installed python only for my user.
I assume I need to setup some environment variables, but don’t know which ones.
Can you please help?

P.S. My linux is not conntected to Web, so need to download all packages seperatly.

Comment: whats is your distribution?

Comment: Install packages from the source code will generate a lot of errors, in addition I assume that you do not have updated your libraries, I recommend you connect to the internet and install it from the repositories of your Linux distribution.

Comment: as I mentioned, I dont have access to the internet from Linux

Comment: This is my linux version:  >>uname -r
2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

Comment: @haykp. If you don't have access to the internet, how did you download the source code? Anyway, you probably installed pyqt to the wrong location. When you build it, you need to specify the full path to the python executable you want to use. If you look in the `site-packages` directory of the python you are using, it should have a sub-directory called `PyQt4`.

Comment: Our Linux is connected to our internal network and cannot connect to external network. There exists site-packages but it contains only sip files. No PyQt4 is there, unfortunatly((